# Unity - how to destroy both colliding instances of a prefab and than spawn a new prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make it so when two instances of a prefab "Enemy" collide they are both destroyed and than another "Enemy" instance is created where the collision happened. I have made it so they are both destroyed but I cannot figure out how to make it so only one spawns. Below is my code for the Enemy. Thank you so much for your help.

```
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Transform target;
    public EnemyMovement code;
    void Awake()
    {
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, 
 speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -transform.eulerAngles.z);
        transform.LookAt(target.position, transform.up);
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0), Space.Self);
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Killer(Clone)")
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Enemy(Clone)")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The name may not work because they may not all be called that surely. If they are both enemy check if the colliding with object also has enemymovement  and if it does spawn a new enemy and then destroy bot yourself and the other?

Comment: Do you know exactly how I could do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: See above?  Seriously. This script is one half. So you know it’s got the component. The parameter provides the collider on the other object which has a game object….

Answer (score 0):

According to the code above, I suspect that you are looking for `Instantiate`. Give the first parameter of the **prefab**, the second is the location and the third is the angle.

```cs
[SerializeField] private GameObject enemyPrefab;
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.transform.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);

        var newObj = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, (transform.position + col.transform.position) / 2, quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```